# Is There A Way To Wrap PHPBB Forums And MediaWiki Into Default Layout Of CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, mediawiki, phpbb

Has anyone successfully been able to do this?
I want MediaWiki and PHPBB to have the same header and footer as my website (default.ctp)

So instead of

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

I would want to echo PHPBB or MediaWiki.

If you have a code example please paste here,
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Integrating PhpBB or Mediawiki with Cake will not be a quick job. The easiest thing to do is to install those applications separately and load them in an iframe.